# Why is the speed of an electron constant in constant magnetic field?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electrons

I had known for long time that the magnetic Lorentz force $F= q \cdot (B \times v)$ acts on an electron so as to make it circle with this speed ($v$).
Recently I tried to imagine how this happens and found that I get a picture incompatible with this fact. I consider the case in the following pattern: The force F creates a speed component perpendicular to v which is infinitesimal at the beginning dv. One must add v and dv and gets the new vector **v**n. Now this the new speed is on the arc of the circle but it is not the same magnitude as v but a bit bigger. Then B acts on it with F and one gets new d**v**-> d**v**p. It is greater than the first dv (first because v=at and a = const but t is greater than dt (it is 2dt), and secondly because **v**n is > v). Repeating this, one will get ever greater velocity of the electron on the circle and not a constant one.
Referring to centrifugal force is not appropriate as I think because I don’t use non-inertial frame.
Then why velocity in constant B does not change?
PS: This is also valid for every force perpendicular to velocity, I think?

Comment: Possible duplicate/relevant question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589107/23615

Comment: The difference in magnitude happens because you're approximating, and goes away as you take the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, an electron moving in a constant, uniform magnetic field will not have constant speed. As the other answers have explained, we would naïvely expect this, since the Lorentz force is necessarily always orthogonal to the velocity, meaning that the magnitude of the velocity will not change. For more detail on that, see the question Triatticus linked above.

However, while the Lorentz force will not change the magnitude of the electron's velocity, it will change its direction, meaning that the electron will have nonzero acceleration. The reason that this is important is because acceleration charges produce radiation, meaning that we must also account for the effect of the [Abraham-Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force), given by
$$\vec F = \frac{\mu_0 q^2}{6\pi c}\dot{\vec a}$$
where $\dot{\vec a}$ is the jerk. If the take the acceleration we would expect from uniform circular motion, we find that $\dot{\vec a}$ is in the opposite direction of velocity, so this force will actually cause the electron to slow down. This is why we don't have cyclotrons which collide electrons, because this effect makes it too difficult to maintain high enough speeds for them. (For heavier particles like protons, the effect is comparatively smaller, thus allowing for proton cyclotrons.)

Comment: Very interesting. I find that the ratio of the A-L force to the Lorentz force on a charged particle in a circular path in a magnetic field is$$\frac{F_{A-L}}{F_L}= \frac{\mu_0 Q^3 B}{6\pi cm^2}.$$ For an electron in a field of 0.01 T this ratio works out to be $1.1 \times 10^{-14}$. Rather small!

Answer (score 1):

Denote the magnitudes of the radius vector and its rate of change by $r$ and $v$ respectively. After an infinitesimal time $\text dt$, the new magnitude is $$\sqrt{r^2 + v^2 \text dt^2}$$ We can apply the binomial expansion to obtain $$r + \frac{v^2}{2r} \text dt^2 + \cdots$$
We can see that the change does not contain any term in $\text dt$ as the highest-order term is $\text dt^2$. Therefore, integrating this change over any period of time will not produce a change in $r$. However, thinking in terms of a finite step size will produce a change in $r$, which is where your reasoning is wrong.

Comment: I think you just have proven that a moving particle is at rest.

Answer (score 0):

Because the magnetic Lorentz force is always at right angles to the particle velocity, and therefore to the instantaneous displacement, the force can do no work on the particle. Therefore the particle cannot gain or lose kinetic energy by the action of this force. Its speed therefore stays constant. But the force must change the particle's velocity. We deduce that the force must continuously change the particle's direction of travel.

Comment: This is all right of course. But what is wrong in my reasoning in the question? That's what I am asking.

Comment: "Now this the new speed is on the arc of the circle but it is not the same magnitude as v but a bit bigger." That would be the case if d$\vec v$ were of finite length, but it isn't, because as $\vec v$ changes direction, the 'first' d$\vec v$ is replaced by a d$\vec v$ in a different direction – at right angles to the new $\vec v$.

Answer (score 0):

You experimentally see that $\vec{F}$ is orthogonal to velocity $\vec{v}$.
You can prove that the magnetic force doesn't make work and the kinetic energy variation in $0$ is this way: $$\Delta E_k=\int_A^B\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s}=\int_A^B(\vec{F}_L\cdot\vec{v})dt=0$$ because $\vec{F}_L$ (Lorentz force) and $\vec{v}$ are orthogonal and so $\vec{B}$ cannot do work on the charge. This implies that the magnetic field redirects the charge motion. Therefore the particle cannot gain or lose kinetic energy.
Being always perpendicular to the direction, the Lorentz force acts as a centripetal force for a velocity particle perpendicular to the direction of the magnetic field.
Out of curiosity this motion is called *cyclotronic*.
I hope this can answer your question.

Comment: You are right and I know these things. But the point is that I would like to understand what is wrong in my reasoning outlaid in the question above.

Comment: At the beginning of your pattern you can't have a velocity bigger than the first one. I think you can't add like this velocities. Changing direction doesn't implie that the magnitude increase. The force creates an acceleration (centripetal). The tangential acceleration is $0$ so the tangential velocity is constant. I wouldn't want to say something wrong. In this case correct me.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous post on this question says, it can be shown that classical E&M predicts that as the electron accelerates, it radiates energy away, causing its speed to change. However, if we ignore this for a second and consider it at the level of an introductory E&M course (general physics 2) we can calculate the work done as
\begin{equation}
W = \int q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{r}.
\end{equation}
Now since we are physicists, we can play around with the infinitesimal path element and see that
\begin{equation}
W = \int q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}\cdot\vec{v}dt = 0.
\end{equation}
This is a mathematical "proof", but an intuitive understanding does come in.

As you said, you can imagine adding a small $d\vec{v}$ at each time step. But you have to remember that this $d\vec{v}$ is a vector that is perpendicular to the original velocity vector, and it is in the exact right amount such that the speed is unchanged (meaning that the particle moves around in a circle).